# Avoiding unnecessary set accessor for TwoWay DataBinding to Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am binding a DataGrid to an ObservableCollection as:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

The property in the viewmodel looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyType> MyCollection
{
    get { return this.Model.Collection; }
    set { /* Empty but needed for data binding */ }
}
```

The set accessor for `MyCollection` is never called or used but is required by the TwoWay DataBinding.  The contained Model class initializes Collection at construction because it is required to place the object in a valid state.  Is there anyway to get around this unnecessary accessor or are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: If the binding is `TwoWay` you need a `set` accessor. If you don't need the accessor then the binding should be `OneWay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Mode=OneWay and you don't need a set.

Answer (score 0):

If the two-way binding is being used both ways, then it is being used, just not explicitly by you in code. As far as I know, you can't get around declaring it. The same with declaring any read-write property. For whatever reason, you have to write them out as

```
Public Type Property
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

MS didn't want to make it TOO easy for you. =)

Comment: How would you expect to declare a read-write property? I found this way the easiest I've seen until now.

Comment: I wasn't arguing against it. I love that you don't have to declare an underlying variable if you don't want to, like VB.

Answer (score 0):

OneWay is concerned with Getter and OneWayToSource is Setter. Of course, TwoWay is concerned with Getter and Setter.

At the point of view, how can you change ItemsSource of DataGrid in View like Text of TextBox? I think it is impossible, so you don't need to set TwoWay binding. Change to OneWay and remove the setter.